# Show traceback of an exception raised by a manually invoked function in ipdb

Tags: python, traceback, ipdb

```
ipdb> def aaaa(q): q[2]
ipdb> aaaa([1,2,3,4])
ipdb> aaaa([])
*** IndexError: list index out of range
ipdb>
```

I want to have a full traceback displayed (pretty one - with stack frames, locals, etc.), not only '*** IndexError: list index out of range'. How do I do that?